# Explanation of Node.js event emitter source code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking at the source for Node.js event emitter

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/events.js

I am trying to figure out how the code identifies a function, specifically when using `addListener`/`removeListener`

those functions both accept a signature of (String s, Function f)

but what I don't understand is how they identify which function to remove when removeListener is called, as there may be multiple functions that serve as callbacks for the same event.

I suppose I am specifically wondering how this line

```
list[i] === listener
```

that is, comparing two functions for equality, works in JS

Answer (score 6):

> but what I don't understand is how they identify which function to
>   remove when removeListener is called, as there may be multiple
>   functions that serve as callbacks for the same event.

An `eventEmitter` object (or anything that inherits from it) stores a map of all the event names that it is managing listeners for.  It can then store an array of functions for each event name in the map.  `addListener()` adds a function to the right list and `removeListener()` removes the matching function from the right list.  When you do:

```
obj.addListener("someEvent", someFunction);
```

The `eventEmitter` object is making sure that "someEvent" is in the map of event names that it is managing and it is adding someFunction to an array of listeners for that specific event name.  There can be more than one listener for a given event name so anytime there is more than one, the `eventEmitter` uses an array so it can store all the listener functions for that specific event.

The code for both `addListener()` and `removeListener()` is complicated quite a bit by an optimization that both implement and that makes it more difficult to follow the code.  If there is more than one listener for a given event, then the code stores an array of listener functions in the event map.  But, if there is only one listener, then it just stores the one listener (no array).  That means that any code that uses the listener list has to first check if it's a single listener or an array of listeners.

`removeListener()` takes two arguments, an event type and a function.  The goal is to find a previously registered listener for that event that registered that specific function and remove them.

The emitter object itself stores an array of functions for each type of event.  So, when `removeListener(type, listener)` is called, the caller is passing in an event type and a specific function.  The eventEmitter code will look in its data to find the list of listeners for the specific type of event that was passed in and then search that list of listeners for one that matches the specific listener that was passed in.  If it is found, it will be removed.

Here's an annotated copy of the code that should explain what's going on in each block of code within the `removeListener()` function:

```
// emits a 'removeListener' event iff the listener was removed
EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener =
    function removeListener(type, listener) {
      var list, events, position, i;

      // make sure that listener was passed in and that it's a function
      if (typeof listener !== 'function')
        throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');

      // get the map of events we have listeners for
      events = this._events;
      if (!events)
        return this;

      // get the list of functions for the specific event that was passed in
      list = events[type];
      if (!list)
        return this;

      // handle some special cases when there is only one listener for an event
      if (list === listener || (list.listener && list.listener === listener)) {
        if (--this._eventsCount === 0)
          this._events = {};
        else {
          delete events[type];
          if (events.removeListener)
            this.emit('removeListener', type, listener);
        }
      } else if (typeof list !== 'function') {
        // when not a special case, we will have to find the right
        // function in the array so initialize our position variable
        position = -1;

        // search backward through the array of functions to find the
        // matching function
        for (i = list.length; i-- > 0;) {
          if (list[i] === listener ||
              (list[i].listener && list[i].listener === listener)) {
            position = i;
            break;
          }
        }

        // if we didn't find it, nothing to do so just return
        if (position < 0)
          return this;

        // if the list has only one function in it, then just clear the list
        if (list.length === 1) {
          list[0] = undefined;
          if (--this._eventsCount === 0) {
            this._events = {};
            return this;
          } else {
            delete events[type];
          }
        } else {
          // remove that one function from the array
          spliceOne(list, position);
        }

        // send out an event if we actually removed a listener
        if (events.removeListener)
          this.emit('removeListener', type, listener);
      }

      return this;
    };
```

---

**Added Explanation based on comments:**

Functions in Javascript are first class objects.  When code uses either `==` or `===` to compare two functions or to compare a variable to a function reference, Javascript just compares to see if each operand refers to the same underlying Javascript object.  There is no `.toString()` being used here.  It's just testing to see if they refer to the same physical object.

Here are a couple examples:

```
function myFunc() {
   console.log("hello");
}

var a = myFunc;
if (a === myFunc) {
    console.log("Yes, a does refer to myFunc");
}

var b = a;
if (b === a) {
    console.log("Yes, a and b refer to the same function");
}

function myFunc2() {
   console.log("hello");
}

a = myFunc;
b = myFunc2;

if (a !== b) {
    console.log("a and b do not refer to the same function");
}
```

Or, a little more like what is being used in `addListener()` and `removeListener()` in a working snippet:

```js
function myFunc() {
   console.log("hello");
}

var list = [];
log("Items in list initially: " + list.length);
list.push(myFunc);
log("Items in list after adding: " + list.length);

// search through list to find and remove any references to myFunc
for (var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list[i] === myFunc) {
         list.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

log("Items in list after find/remove: " + list.length);

// helper function to log output
function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: thanks! I am wondering how "list[i] === listener" works when comparing functions - looks like they are using === to compare functions...but how does that actually work in JS? I thought objects/functions in JS don't have id's of any kind?

Comment: when comparing two functions f1 === f2, does JS do a toString() on each function and then compare? That seems bad for multiple reasons.

Comment: @AlexMills - Functions are first class objects in Javascipt.  So, `===` in this case just compares to see if the two operands refer at the same exact function.  In javascript, you can do: `function myFunc() {...}; var fn = myFunc;  if (fn === myFunc) {...}`.  That's all that's going on here.  Functions are just an object reference just like any other object reference in JS.

Comment: @AlexMills - No, it does not do a `.toString()`.  It compares to see if they physically refer to the same underlying Javascript object.  It's just like: `var a = {greeting: "hello"}; var b = a;  if (b === a) {...}`;

Comment: @AlexMills - See examples I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @AlexMills - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.

Answer (score 1):

The code finds the function by doing comparisons similar to the following:

```
var events = [/*...*/];
function removeListener(type, fn){
    for(var z = 0; z < events.length; z++){
         if(events[z] === fn){
             // fn event listener is equal to
             // the zth element of events, so
             // remove this element
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: But, this isn't actually what the actual `eventEmitter` code does.  An answer to this question should explain what the actual `eventEmitter` code does, not how a removeListener function could work in theory.

Comment: @jfriend00 this is pretty much what the `removeListener` code does. It might be easier to understand in a small, minimal example than an entire code dump

Answer (score 1):

`addListener` and `removeListener` require you to pass in a function. That function gets stored in a dictionary that maps the specific event to the function(s) registered for that event.

In order for `removeListener` to work, you have to pass in the **same** function that was passed into `addListener`. Understand that in JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens. In simple terms, this means you can assign a function to a variable and pass functions as arguments to other functions.

Here's an example of using `addListener` and then removing with `removeListener`,

```
var cb = function() {
  console.log('event emitted');
}

emitter.addListener('event', cb);

// We can then remove the association by passing in cb as the
// second argument to removeListener
emitter.removeListener('event', cb);
```

Alternatively, we can use named functions to avoid assigning the function to a variable.

```
emitter.addListener('event', function cb() {
  console.log('event emitted');
});

// Remove
emitter.removeListener('event', cb);
```

Since functions are first-class citizens, they can be stored and compared directly. Using this, `removeListener` just iterates its internal list until it finds the particular function object.